# How to find the spot which is furthest away?

Tags: complexity-theory

Last night I thought about the following problem:

 
**Given any map (for example from Germany), how to find the spot which is furthest away (in every direction) from the nearest (any) town/village?**

 
I thought about how one would proceed to figure out in which problem class this problem belongs to and how to prove that. 
And also how to determine which would be an efficient algorithm for this problem. 
 
Basically I would like to learn about the steps how a professional in complexity theory would start to work on a problem like this.

 
I read on Wikipedia about the [Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) which I think come close to what I'm looking for. But I wasn't able to find something like "furthest neighbor search".

Comment: Start by computing the Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 1):

As you get further from Germany, you will get points which are farther and farther away. So unless you are taking into account the spherical nature of Earth, we need to change the problem, and look for a location *in Germany* which is farthest away from all villages in Germany. This is known as the [largest empty circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_sphere) problem, and can be solved essentially by computing the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the set of villages in Germany.

Comment: _look for a location in Germany which is farthest away from all villages in Germany_ is basically the problem I tried to formulate. I didn't know this is already a know problem. Thank you very much for the links, I'm going to read them. 
But would the problem or the solution change if we take the spherical nature of Earth into account too?

Comment: Presumably you'll need to calculate a Voronoi diagram on the sphere, but otherwise the solution would be very similar (and in fact easier, since we don't need to worry about the boundary).